# ggvis: add size property to a line

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggvis

Just getting started with `ggvis`. Not a particularly interesting or general question I'm afraid, but its is not obvious to me how to add a `size` property to a line. In particular, how would I replicate the following plot using `ggvis`?

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
  x  = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4),
  y  = c(2,3,4,1,1,2,3)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = as.factor(id), size = id)) +
  geom_line()
```

Also, could someone with a high enough reputation create a `ggvis` tag? Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following:

```
library(ggvis)

gg <- ggvis(df, props(~x, ~y, stroke = ~factor(id)))
gg <- gg + layer_line(props(strokeWidth := ~id*4))
gg
```

produces:

[image: plot]

I had to tweak the multiplier for the `strokeWidth` to get it to be a bit thicker, but that should be a good starting point for you. Remember `ggivs` is based on [Vega](http://trifacta.github.io/vega/) so getting familiar with the terminology in that new graphics grammar is going to almost be a requirement to understand how to "*think*" in `ggvis`.

Here's an example of doing this more properly (and more `ggplot2`-like with `scale_quantitative`:

```
gg <- ggvis(df, props(~x, ~y, stroke = ~factor(id)))
gg <- gg + layer_line(props(strokeWidth = ~id)) 
gg <- gg + scale_quantitative("strokeWidth",
                              trans="linear", 
                              domain=range(df$id), 
                              range=c(1,10))
gg
```

[image: sq]

Doing a `?scale_quantitative` or reviewing the ["scales" online examples](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/properties-scales.html#properties---scales) should give you a good idea of your options for getting the desired effect.

I also should point out the use of "`=`" vs "`:=`" in the second example. From the `ggvis` site:

> *The props() function uses the = operate for mapping (scaled), and the := operator for setting (unscaled). It also uses the ~ operator to indicate that an expression should be evaluated in the data (and in ggvis, the data can change); without the ~ operator, the expression is evaluated immediately in the current environment.*

Comment: This is what I tried, but without the re-factoring. Reading the Vega documentation, I see that `strokeWidth`defines the stroke width in pixels. Does this mean I have to scale things manually? e.g. when I put `strokeWidth := ~id`, all I'm really trying to show is that the thickness of `id 2` is twice that of `id 1`. Say the `id`s were instead `100` and `200` respectively - then the relative size differences are now clear, but at the expense of the plot looking _nice_. I would have expected I could do something like `strokeWidth = ~id` however, this produces a plot which doesn't render.

Comment: I posted more to the example to show how to do it more "ggplot"-like using `scale_quantitative`. Be glad to explain more as well (to the best of my ability…ggvis is a whole new way of doing things :-)

Comment: I should also add that I don't think `ggvis` is going to be as clean of an abstraction from either D3 or SVG as at least I was hoping it would be. Vega (understandably) has a great deal of D3-isms in it and D3 has (understandably) a great deal of SVG-isms in it (at least in the way it's commonly used). Knowing SVG, D3 and javascript will be key to fully grok'ing `ggvis` (at least IMO).